# Execute Plink on multiple VCF files in the same directory using the MacOS terminal

Tags: bash, loops, command, vcf-vcard

I currently have a number of VCF files that i am converting into plink format. I am doing so by running plink from the terminal with the following parameters.

./plink --vcf BH4_F3_F2.g.vcf.gz --recode --const-fid --allow-extra-chr --out BH4_F3_F2

I however need to run this command on approximately 100 all with different names
 e.g, BH4_F3_F2.g.vcf.gz
      BH4_F2_F1.g.vcf.gz

Is there a way to do this without having to execute each separately?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `for` loop syntax. Something like

```
for vcf in *vcf
do
    ./plink --vcf "$vcf" --recode --const-fid --allow-extra-chr --out "$vcf.plink"
done
```